Skip rows with pandas.read_csv(..., comment="#") but allow hash in the data?
Is there any way in pandas to ignore #-commented lines in their entirety, but leave the # symbol alone in the CSV body?
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv_content = """\
# title: Sample CSV
# description: This dataset
id,name,favourite_hashtag
1,John,#python
2,Jane,#rstats
"""

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_content),comment='#')
print(data)

Right now we get:
   id  name  favourite_hashtag
0   1  John                NaN
1   2  Jane                NaN

If no, is there any hope of making a feature request to that end?

are there only a few rows? skiprows might be sufficient https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

This seems like unintended behavior, you could open an issue in Github. For comparison, this works in Polars pl.read_csv(StringIO(csv_content), comment_prefix="#")

@foglerit: interesting. It's not unintended behaviour though, but a different implementation. pd.read_csv under comment: "Character indicating that the remainder of line should not be parsed. If found at the beginning of a line, the line will be ignored altogether." Versus: pl.read_csv under comment_prefix: "A string used to indicate the start of a comment line." (italics mine).

You could try stripping out the comment lines before loading into the DataFrame. For example, assuming comment lines have # as the first character:
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import csv

csv_content = """\
# title: Sample CSV
# description: This dataset
id,name,favourite_hashtag
#my comment line
1,John,#python
2,Jane,#rstats
"""

stripped = csv.DictReader(filter(lambda row: row[0]!='#', StringIO(csv_content)))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stripped)
print(df)

  id  name favourite_hashtag
0  1  John           #python
1  2  Jane           #rstats

which gives

One solution with pd.read_csv:
csv_content = """\
# title: Sample CSV
# description: This dataset
id,name,favourite_hashtag
1,John,#python
# another comment in the middle
2,Jane,#rstats
"""

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_content), header=2, on_bad_lines="skip")

And if you have comments in the middle of the file:
data = data[data.iloc[:, 0].str[0] != "#"]


